# Parcel alias not registering with tslint

Tags: typescript, parceljs

I'm using parcel-bundler for react with TypeScript, and I've set up some aliases in package.json.

This is my tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["./declarations.d.ts", "global.d.ts"]
}
```

Here are my aliases

```js
"alias": {
  "#types": "./src/types",
  "#App": "./src/App",
  "#helpers": "./src/helpers",
  "#shared": "./src/shared"
}
```

And when I import anything using these aliases

```js
import Button from "#shared/Button";
```

It underlines them, saying `Cannot find module #shared/Button` in Vscode

However, the app runs fine. So how should I tell tslint, that there are aliased imports from parcel?

Answer (score 0):

First, remove all your aliases in package.json to avoid confusion.

Then install it as a dev dependency:

```sh
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

change tilde to hash:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "#*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["./declarations.d.ts", "global.d.ts"]
}
```

add the plugin to `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["."],
      "alias": {
        "#shared": "./src/shared"
      }
   }]
 ]
}
```

**Note**: alias in `babelrc` can't concatenate the directory. It must be a full path.